# xDebug not working with PhpStorm 2016.2

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, ampps

I spent some good hours trying to setup xdebugger to work with PhpStorm 2016.2 with no success. And by that I mean, the breakpoints do not work at all.

I'm running AMPPS on windows for PHP 5.6 server.
Yes, I am restarting Apache at every modification on the `php.ini` file.

I'll put some screenshots of relevant stuff on the hope that someone can spot a mistake.

And here is the error from xdebug:

> Log opened at 2016-11-14 19:39:56 I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001.
>   W: Creating socket for 'localhost:9001', WSAPoll: 10022.
>   W: Creating socket for 'localhost:9001', WSAPoll: 10022.
>   E: Could not connect to client. :-(
>   Log closed at 2016-11-14 19:39:56

[image: PhpStorm config screen]

[image: Xdebug php.ini configs]

If someone could help me on this, I would be very greatful.
At this point I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: Do not use xdebug 2.5 RC on Windows -- it does not work right now. **Use xdebug stable 2.4.1** for now - as simple as this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40803303/783119

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Run -> Edit Configurations.
- Click on the "+" symbol, and go to PHP Remote Debug.
- Fill the "name" field and pick your server from the "Servers" combo (create a new server if you did not already) .
- Set "PHPSTORM" as your ide key.

Then go to https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/ and save the marklets as a bookmark in your browser. Activate the DEBUG one before debugging.

Then it should work, set a breakpoint and start the debug session with the bug button having your server selected in the upper right combo, or from Run -> Debug.

Your apache config looks fine to me.

Hope it helps, feel free to comment if not!

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it!
Unfortunatelly, I had no luck with it.

What really "solved" for me, was to copy the dll that I was using in my other PC.

I will paste it here (the configs with the version of xdebugger), just for the documentation: 

zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=local.piperun
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

With those configurations, no extra setup is needed.
Thanks